# Why is Algolia Client not resolved in android studio?

Tags: android, algolia, saas, instantsearch

I don't know why android studio is not able to resolve Client and Query from the import statements:

```java
import com.algolia.search.saas.Client;
import com.algolia.search.saas.Query;
```

It is showing cannot resolve Client and Query on the both import statements.

This is present in my app Gradle file:

```gradle
implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-android:1.15.0'
```

I tried invalidating caches and restart multiple times and even tried to change the version of Algolia dependency in Gradle file above, but nothing worked.

I am not able to understand why is this happening, I would appreciate if someone could help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/installation/android/

```
dependencies {
    // [...]
    implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-android:1.+'
    // This will automatically update to the latest v1 release of InstantSearch

    // OR
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.+'
    // This will automatically update to the latest v3 release of the client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try including this also

implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx-core:1.15.2'

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the androidx libraries so your mileage may vary, but adding

```
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.27.0'
```

resolved the problem for me.